# How to merge multiple (arbitrary number of) Set<String> into one in Java?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have multiple `Set<String>` that I need to merge into one `Set<String>`. How do I do this operation in Java? Note, I am using using the `guava` API as best as I can to help out. For example, I have 3 classes as follows.

```
public class One {
 public static Set<String> SET = Sets.newHashSet("a","b","c");
}
public class Two {
 public static Set<String> SET = Sets.newHashSet("a","d","e","f");
}
public class Three {
 public static Set<String> SET = Sets.newHashSet("w","x","y","f");
}
```

Now, I need to merge any combination of these sets into one. For, example, I may need to merge

- `One.SET` + `Two.SET` + `Three.SET` into one to produce { "a","b","c","d","e","f","w","x","y" },
- `One.SET` + `Three.SET` into one to produce { "a","b","c","w","x","y","f" },
- `Two.SET` + `Three.SET` into one to produce { "a","d","e","f","w","x","y" },
- and so on

I created a method to merge an array of sets, `Set<String>[]`, but that doesn't work (explained here by this SO post [Creating an array of Sets in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999192/creating-an-array-of-sets-in-java)). Here's the code to merge. It works (compiles).

```
public static Set<String> immutableSetOf(Set<String>[] sets) {
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
 for(Set<String> s : sets) {
  set.addAll(s);
 }
 return ImmutableSet.copyOf(set);
}
```

Here's the calling code; it doesn't work (doesn't compile).

```
Set<String> set = Utils.immutableSetOf(new Set<String>[] { One.SET, Two.SET });
```

So, I modified my merging method to operate on `List<Set<String>>` instead of `Set<String>[]`. Only the argument type changed, but I put it here for completeness.

```
public static Set<String> immutableSetOf(List<Set<String>> sets) {
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
 for(Set<String> s : sets) {
  set.addAll(s);
 }
 return ImmutableSet.copyOf(set);
}
```

So, now my calling code looks like the following.

```
Set<String> set = Utils.immutableSetOf(
 Lists.newArrayList(
  One.SET, Two.SET));
```

This code does not compile, since `Lists.newArrayList(...)` is returning `Set<String>` and not `List<Set<String>>`. The method `Lists.newArrayList(...)` is overloaded, and the signature of the method that is used when I pass in sets is, `List.newArrayList(Iterable<? extends E> elements)`.

So, the question is, how do I define a method to merge an arbitrary number of `Set<String>` while considering the calling code? I note that the compilation problems are on the calling code (not the merging method), but perhaps the solution also relates to the merging code?

Update: I also tried varargs but that produces its own warning ([Is it possible to solve the "A generic array of T is created for a varargs parameter" compiler warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445233/is-it-possible-to-solve-the-a-generic-array-of-t-is-created-for-a-varargs-param)). The merging method signature is now the following.

```
public static Set<String> immutableSetOf(Set<String>... sets)
```

The calling code is now the following, and I get "Type safety: A generic array of Set is created for a varargs parameter".

```
Set<String> set = Utils.immutableSetOf(One.SET, Two.SET);
```

Update: For the accepted answer, I did the following.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Set<String> set = Utils.immutableSetOf(Set[] { One.SET, Two.SET });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your previous attempt, you had written

```
Set<String> set = Utils.immutableSetOf(new Set<String>[] { One.SET, Two.SET });
```

This does not work because, generics array creation is not allowed in java

Try this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Set<String>[] mySet = new Set[] { One.SET, Two.SET };
Set<String> set = Utils.immutableSetOf(mySet);
```

The reason this works is because, we create a new Set[] without specifying the generics type and assign it to the reference Set[] mySet (since this is an unchecked operation, we have to add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to it)

Comment: That definitely works, but is there a way while specifying the generic type?

Comment: From what i know, the java does not allow it. Also, there is no need for it, as at the end of the day, we need to have a reference with the specified type, which can be accomplished.

Comment: Recommend com.google.common.collect.Sets#union(set1, set2) to get the merge instead of Set.addAll under hood, since Guava is already in your dependencies.

Reason: it's view which is memory effective, and also unmodifiable.

Answer (score 6):

Recommend `com.google.common.collect.Sets#union(set1, set2)` to get the merge instead of `Set.addAll` under hood, since Guava is already in your dependencies.

Reason: it's **view** which is memory effective, and also **unmodifiable**.

plus: I should have post it as a *comment*, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

How about creating a collection of your input sets, then using `flatMap`?

```
Set<String> allElements = ImmutableSet.of(
        One.SET,
        Two.SET,
        Three.SET
).stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I'd do `Stream.of(One.SET, Two.SET, Three.SET)` rather than `ImmutableSet.of().stream()` to avoid unnecessarily creating the interim `ImmutableSet`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
Set<String> set = immutableSetOf(Arrays.asList(One.SET, Two.SET));
```

Using your definition of `immutableSetOf(List<Set<String>> sets)`.  No warnings or suppressed warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that `FluentIterable` (in 18.0 and above) can help here, specifically the [`append` method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#append(java.lang.Iterable)).

With that, we need to define a convenient helper method - and yes, we're going to use varargs for this.

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> Set<T> mergeSets(Set<T> initial,
                                                 Set<T>... rest) {
    FluentIterable<T> result =  FluentIterable.from(initial);
    for(Set<T> set : rest) {
        result = result.append(set);
    }
    return new TreeSet<>(result.toSet());
}
```

The resultant set here is in natural order.  If you don't want a `TreeSet` and you don't want to mutate your collection afterwards, then omit the `new TreeSet<>` piece, and loosen the bound on `T`.

Comment: `warning: [unchecked] Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type Set<T>`

Answer (score 0):

This should help. One liner in Java 8:

```
Stream.of(sets).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```